# How to Install Pycharm and its default settings on users Virtual machine

Tags: pycharm

How to install Pycharm on Non persistant Virtual Machines and set default settings for every user?

I have installed PyCharm Community Edition 2020 on a Windows 10 VM.

I have configured Python 3.7 Interpreter and a Virtual Environment in PyCharm with Administrator login but if I login as a different user I am not getting the settings (Python 3.7 interpreter and Virtual Environment setup in Administrator login)

Achieved: From the Administrator login if I go to File > Settings > Export Settings and export the settings and import it in another user login then
I can see the Python 3.7 interpreter in Virtual environment.
I want to know how to script the configuration settings Export and Import

Or is there any command line tools in Pycharm for exporting and importing the configuration settings.

Comment: Would you mind adding more detail? Are you trying to do this programmatically, i.e. in a repeatable way, as suggested by "for every user?", or do you just need it installed on your VM host for sandboxing? Also, what os(s) are you running, what hypervisor implementation, etc?

Comment: @NathanToulbert Please ignore my earlier question. I just want to know Is there any command line tools in Pycharm for exporting and importing the configuration settings?